# Android app crashing while running using Firebase FireStore and Database(java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTokenProvider)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new to android and when I'm running the app and it's crashing and giving the below error in LogCat.
I'm using firebase fireStore and Authentication in this project

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTokenProvider(Lcom/google/firebase/internal/InternalTokenProvider;)V in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.learnerplus-kKFQP8AoAlLtMcAS4duBIQ==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:69)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:53)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:158)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(FirebaseApp.java:583)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:304)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:268)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:253)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6638)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6185)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6100)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1807)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
```

**build.gradle(app)**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.learnerplus"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    //compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:7.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03'

    def nav_version = "2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.0'

}
```

**bulid.gradle(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

P.S.-I'm using both java and kotlin files in this project and I tried Invalidate Cache and Restart and clean solution.

Comment: Try using the latest version of `firebase-auth`

Comment: @Kidus I upgraded the firebase-auth to 20.0.1 but now it's giving error 

Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun onVerificationCompleted(p0: PhoneAuthCredential): Unit defined in com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

Comment: Try multiDexEnabled true in defaultConfig